# Java checking connection via socket continuously

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm developing a multiclient-server program with Java based on GUI and database. The demand regarding the program from the client side is to make sure all the time that there is a connection to the server, and if the connection is lost (server goes down/problem with socket or stream) it should be notified.

In other words I need a solution for continuously checking the connection to the server.

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

implement a heart beat protocol...

if you dont what to do that, you can use a connection listener thread 
[`Socket.isConnected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29)

Comment: Socket.isComnected() only tells you whether you have ever connected the *socket.* It doesn't know anything about the state of the *connection.*

Comment: it tells you if a socket is bound and successfully connected...actually a state of the connection, next time read the references and then vote down!

Comment: You're guessing: I'm not. Clearly you have never tried it. isConnected() doesn't tell you whether the connection is still alive, which is the topic of the question. Your suggestion amounts to wasting an entire thread on testing whether the socket got connected in the first place, which is completely pointless. There is in fact no way to implement an isConnected() method that behaves as you have assumed here, as TCP doesn't provide such an API.

Comment: i don't assume, i know for a fact! next time do your testing! isConnected() tells you if you ever occupied a socket and established a connection, for the purpose of the question, documentation, reference AND yours "hwoknowswhat" this IS an(the) answer. no api fyi provied an isConnected method that does what the question mentioned, so if u kindly notice my first suggestion was an HB protocol...and if you really knew your sockets you would know that the send method rises an exception if the endpoint socket is not receiving....

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in TCP/IP. The only way to detect a connection failure in TCP is to try to use it. You might consider adding a heartbeat to the protocol, but it might be better to review the requirement with the client side guys. TCP/IP doesn't have a 'dial tone', by design, and adding one at the application level is non-trivial, error-prone, and carries a time and space overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the socket connection is closed.

```
if(Socket.isClosed()) {
    //reconnect or alert the user
} //end if
```

Comment: That only tells you whether you have closed the socket yourself. It doesn't tell you about the connection. Clearly you haven't tried it. -1.